# Entity Framework add row with id based on regex

Tags: entity-framework

I've got two tables with a one to many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE Super (
  SuperId VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Sub (
  SubId VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  SuperId VARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Super(SuperId)
)
```

What I'm trying to do is let the entity framework take care of generating the SubId based on a regex sequence. The db I'm working with has the SubId start with the SuperId. What comes after doesn't matter as long as it's unique.

```
INSERT INTO Super(SuperId) VALUES
('12345')

INSERT INTO Sub(SubId, SuperId) VALUES
('123451', '12345'),
('123452', '12345')
```

I'm looking to be able to do something like this:

```
Sub mySub = new Sub();
mySub.SuperId = 12345;

db.Sub.Add(mySub, mySub.SuperId + "*");
```

Where "*" is something unique.

I'm looking to get out of having to query the db in my code to generate a unique id. I know the entity framework can generate a unique id, but that's not what I'm looking for.

No big deal if that functionality isn't in there though. I just don't wanna keep querying the db to check if a key exists, but I will if I have to.

Comment: Creating unique numbers is not a big deal and but it seems you are looking for a way to create sequential unique id without looking db and it would be a big deal.

Comment: You can take a substring from a guid. That should be good enough. Any algorithm that generates strings of restricted length will create duplicate values sooner or later.

Comment: I was more looking for the entity framework to query the db and handle this itself, but it looks like I'll have to do it in my code.

Comment: That's not what I understood from your question. But anyway, EF doesn't have built-in key generation mechanisms, only the ability to read database-generated keys and automatically use that exact value as a foreign key value for child objects. If you want to do it differently, AFAIK you'll have to do it in code or by database triggers.

Comment: All right I'll do it in my code. Was just wondering if there was a short-cut. Thanks for the help guys.